# Error compiling Android app with Material Components and androidX

Tags: android, themes, androidx, material-components-android

Android application suddenly refuses to build, it returns this error:

> Android resource linking failed
>    error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar (aka
>   it.duemilanet.icircle:style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar)
>   not found.
>
> D:\GitLab\iCircleAndroidRMA\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1440:
>   error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondary (aka
>   it.duemilanet.icircle:attr/colorSecondary)' not found.
>       error: resource style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal (aka it.duemilanet.icircle:style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal) not
>   found.
>       error: resource style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog (aka it.duemilanet.icircle:style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog) not
>   found.
>       D:\GitLab\iCircleAndroidRMA\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3296:
>   error: style attribute 'attr/bottomSheetStyle (aka
>   it.duemilanet.icircle:attr/bottomSheetStyle)' not found.
>       error: failed linking references.

It was compiling just fine before, i switched to androidX and material components theme weeks ago and enabled jetifier without problems

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha09'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }

}

allprojects {

    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.duemilanet.icircle"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3334
        versionName "3.3.3.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.5'
    implementation 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.bskim:maxheightscrollview:1.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.pspdfkit:pspdfkit:4.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.18'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.0-alpha12'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://customers.pspdfkit.com/maven/'
        credentials {
            username 'pspdfkit'
            password 'PASSWORD'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

- **I tried to disable Instant Run and to revert to previous versions of the material library but i couldn't fix the error.**

Answer (score 3):

There are several components which are referenced in the material design documentation which aren't yet in a stable release of the material design library for Android. Try using the alpha version instead.

Add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies { 
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I skipped this line. Saved my hours of refactoring )